# Moving specific cells from last row to new spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script that will look for a new entry from a Google Form into a Google Sheet and move data from specific cells to a separate spreadsheet. I have the following script and am having trouble with the rowValues variable. Below is the script as it is currently written.

```
function onEdit(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CopyFromSheet");

var rowId = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
var rowValues (rowId);
Logger.log(rowValues);
var destValues = [];
destValues.push(rowValues[0][0]);// copy data from col A to col A
destValues.push(rowValues[0][1]);// copy data from col B to col B
destValues.push(rowValues[0][2]);// copy data from col C to col C
destValues.push(rowValues[0][5]);// copy data from col F to col D
destValues.push(rowValues[0][6]);// copy data from col G to col E
destValues.push(rowValues[0][7]);// copy data from col H to col F
destValues.push(rowValues[0][8]);// copy data from col I to col G
destValues.push(rowValues[0][21]);// copy data from col V to col H
destValues.push(rowValues[0][23]);// copy data from col X to col I

var dest=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID#').getSheetByName('CopyToSheet'); 
dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `trouble with the rowValues variable` of `I have the following script and am having trouble with the rowValues variable.`? And what is `var rowValues (rowId);`?

Comment: onEdit trigger won't fire when a Google Form writes another line to a sheet.  You should be using onFormSubmit trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var destValues = [];
  destValues.push(e.values[0]);
  destValues.push(e.values[1]);
  destValues.push(e.values[2]);
  destValues.push(e.values[5]);
  destValues.push(e.values[6]);
  destValues.push(e.values[7]);
  destValues.push(e.values[8]);
  destValues.push(e.values[21]);
  destValues.push(e.values[23]);
  var dest=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID#').getSheetByName('CopyToSheet'); 
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);
}
```

Comment: Cooper, using an onFormSubmit function makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out. When running this script, it is pushing data but the data from the first array entry [0][0], in this case, is being sent to the destination sheet/cells 1 character per cell. For instance, the date is the data in the first cell that is being transferred. In the CopyTo sheet, the first cell has '1', the second cell has '2', the third cell has'/', etc. I'm assuming that there is something wrong with dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues/length)...

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that I made a mistake just remove the first sub script zero

Comment: Removing the first sub-script 0 from any line creates an error where I am unable to save the script. Removing the first line from the array just stops the first character '1' from being written.

Comment: That should do it

Comment: Did it! Thanks, Cooper!